# Why does gtk.main_quit() not work?

Tags: python-2.7, gtk, pygtk

I'm new here. :)

I am having trouble emigrating from GTK+ in C to PyGTK, specifically I do not understand why (in this specific context of a pause/play button) gtk.main_quit() does nothing even though it is called.

In my working example, after you press "Play", press "Pause" and then try to use the "Quit" button. On my end the "Quit" button, even though it calls gtk.main_quit() (and prints stuff after it to prove it does), will not have any effect on the program. Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?

Here it is:

```
import pygtk
pygtk.require('2.0')
import gtk, gobject, cairo
import time

global paused
paused = False
running = False

def some_stuff(widget, data=None):
  global paused
  global running
  x = 0
  if running:
    return
  running = True
  paused = False
  while True:
    x += 1
    print x
    while gtk.events_pending():
      gtk.main_iteration(False)
    while paused:
      while gtk.events_pending():
    gtk.main_iteration(False)
  running = False
  paused = False

def pause_stuff(widget, data=None):
  global paused
  paused = not paused

def force_quit(widget, data=None):
  print 'before'
  gtk.main_quit()   # doesn't work, gtk main loop keeps running
  #exit()            # obviously works to kill everything
  print 'after'


def main():
  window = gtk.Window()
  window.connect("delete-event", force_quit)
  window.show()
  vbox = gtk.VBox(True, 3)
  vbox.show()
  window.add(vbox)

  button = gtk.Button("Play")
  button.connect("clicked", some_stuff, None)
  vbox.add(button)
  button.show()

  button = gtk.Button("Pause")
  button.connect("clicked", pause_stuff, None)
  vbox.add(button)
  button.show()

  button = gtk.Button("Quit")
  button.connect("clicked", force_quit, None)
  vbox.add(button)
  button.show()
  window.present()
  gtk.main()
  return 0

if __name__ =="__main__":
  main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding this as answer based on the comment to the other answer (since this is a bit long for a comment). Let's assume that one game iteration is fast and you can do one in gtk main thread without hurting the UI.

1. Make a function that runs one single iteration of your game (to begin with you can just print something). The function should be an "idle handler callback" (see below). It should return True, except if the game is paused or stopped: in that case it should return False (meaning the function should not be called again).
2. In Play() add an [idle handler](https://developer.gnome.org/pygobject/stable/glib-functions.html#function-glib--idle-add) for the iteration function
3. In Pause(), update the paused variable, and if unpausing also add an idle handler like in Play()

This way the iteration function keeps getting called after Play is called (but the UI is also updated). after Pause the iteration function is still called once, but it will return False and will not be called again.

Answer (score 2):

`gtk.main_quit()` instructs the GTK main loop to terminate. It has no effect in your code because your `some_stuff()` function implements its own version of the main loop, unaffected by calls to `gtk.main_quit()`. Since the outer `while` never exits, once the Play button is clicked, you never return into the real GTK main loop.

A correct GTK program does not reimplement the main loop like `some_stuff()` does, precisely to avoid such problems, and also to avoid busy-looping while nothing is going on. The `while gtk.events_pending(): gtk.main_iteration()` idiom should be used very sparingly, only when absolutely necessary (updating a progress bar comes to mind).

Comment: Thanks so much for the reply, how should I be doing this instead?

Comment: some_stuff doesn't actually do anything so we can't give advice on how you should do "this" because we don't know what this is :)  Generally speaking you want to use libraries that you can call asynchronously (so some_stuff() can return after making a call, and you will get a callback later on). If you really need to execute a long-running call, you should do it in another thread so the gtk main loop is not disturbed.

Comment: PS: Apologies, for the `while True:`, `while Condition:` where `Condition` is set to `False` by a "Stop" button, obviously, has the same problems. Should I implement this in such a way that the "Pause" button actually causes `some_stuff` to `return`?

Comment: @jku Yeah, sorry, I wanted  a small piece of code so I removed a lot of stuff. Imagine that "Play" sets off Conway's Game of Life, and that "Pause" makes it stop at the current iteration.

Comment: I think this one is the correct answer to your original question, but I added another to answer the "new questions" in your comment.

Comment: I think my reputation is not high enough to select a correct answer?

Comment: @Olivia jku's answer correctly describes what you should be doing instead (+1). Note that this doesn't only apply to GTK, but also to any event-driven toolkit, i.e. essentially to all GUI toolkits in current use.

Comment: OK, done. I think I might have picked up some bad habits re: gtk in C. Good thing I'm not carrying them over.